# Trying to copy and move a record number from the middle of a file name to the front of a file name, word document, using RStudio

Tags: r, rename, batch-rename

I am trying to take a folder of word documents and rename them, each has a species name, possible observation count, e.g. 2 of 10, country identifier, e.g. [C] for Cambodia, date that might be . seperated or not, a field record number, given by fr# before the number and brackets that might be ( , [ or {, with location name in text at the end. Example:

```
species name 2 of 10 [C] 27.Aug.12 [Fr#2046] location name.doc
```

I need to remove the fr# at add it onto the front of the file name, the original fr# can remain in the middle also, Example:

```
2046 species name 2 of 10 [C] 27.Aug.12 [Fr#2046] location name.doc
```

I've managed to remove the front of the name to show the number, but have struggled to do anything else.

```
library(stringr)            #install stingr from library
my_path <- "/Users/Documents/RStudio_Docs/Field _Record_Rename/"  # Define working directory
my_path                                   # Print path to working directory
file_names_old <- list.files(my_path)              # Get current file names
file_names_old                                     # Print current file names
sub(".*#", "",file_names_old)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. My windows is old school, but I recall that file names couldn't start with a number, though perhaps that has changed?

Comment: @Chris I'm pretty sure windows file names have been able to start with a number for at least 25 years... not sure about Windows 95.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `stringr::str_extract` to get the numbers preceded by "Fr#" and then `paste` them to the start of the file name:

```
x = "species name 2 of 10 [C] 27.Aug.12 [Fr#2046] location name.doc"

fr = str_extract(x, "(?<=Fr#)\\d+")
x = paste(fr, x)
x
# [1] "2046 species name 2 of 10 [C] 27.Aug.12 [Fr#2046] location name.doc"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, I added in the code, now I just need to output the renamed files

`file_names_old <- list.files(my_path)              # Get current file names
file_names_old                            # Print current file names
x = file_names_old
x

fr = str_extract(x, "(?<=Fr#)\\d+")

file_names_new = paste (fr, x)

file_names_new

file.rename(paste0(my_path, x), paste0(my_path, file_names_new))`